# Show last inserted record in Textbox using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to show last inserted record in textarea which is tinymce editor after I press submit button the record should get submitted and 
with the help of id the same record should be fetched from database with the help of model and returned to controller and then passed
on to view, but I'm unable to pass the last inserted record from model to controller and view. Please help to sort out my issue.

> Controller:

```
public function create_user(){

    $goal1=$this->input->get_post('description1');
    $goal2=$this->input->get_post('description2');
    $goal3=$this->input->get_post('description3');


    $id=$this->input->post('c_id');  

    $data=array('goal1'=>$goal1,'goal2'=>$goal2,'goal3'=>$goal3);
    $result_goal = $this->course_user->create_user($data,$id);

    //Code to retrieve last record

    $result_updated_record = $this->course_model->get_last_record($id);

    if($result_updated_record!='false')
    { 
        return $result_updated_record;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

> Model:

```
public function get_last_record($last_id)
{
   $condition = "id =" . "'" . $last_id . "'";
   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from("goal");
   $this->db->where($condition);
   $query=$this->db->get();
   $res = $query->result_array();
}
```

> View:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "<?php echo base_url();?>c_user/create_user",
       cache: false,                
       data: dataString,
       success: function(data){

        tinymce.get('id_description1').setContent('');
        tinymce.get('id_description2').setContent('');
        tinymce.get('id_description3').setContent('');

    },
    error: function(){                      
        alert('Error while request...');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->db->insert_id()` which will return last inserted record primary key.

Comment: Thanks Rockers, but i want to know to pass it from model to view via controller

Comment: Model function looks like this which return primary key in both cases update and insert...
 function AddInsertUpdateTable($table, $key_name, $key_value, $data)
    {
        if ($key_name != '' && $key_value != '') {
            $this->db->where($key_name, $key_value);
            $query = $this->db->update($table, $data);

            return $key_value;
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }